# How to strong type electron.remote.require() result

Tags: typescript, electron, typescript-typings

In the renderer process of an electron application developed with Typescript, I have for instance:

```js
import {remote} from 'electron';
const Fs = remote.require('fs');
```

where `Fs` is of type `any`

I would like `Fs` to be of type "module:fs" but I don't know how to achieve this in Typescript:

```js
const Fs = remote.require('fs') // as module:fs ??
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

Create a file, say `augmentations.d.ts` and specify its contents as follows

```
// Augmentations are only valid in modules.
// This ensures this file is parsed as a module.
export {} 

import fs from 'fs';

declare module 'electron' {
  interface Remote {
    require(moduleSpecifier: 'fs'): typeof fs;
  }
}
```

This augments the declaration of electron's `Remote` interface, adding an overload of `require` which associates the string literal type `"fs"` with the type of the default export of NodeJS's `"fs"` module as declared by `@types/node` and installed as a dependency of `election`.

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charm: ```remote.require('fs')``` is not any anymore with this ambient declaration

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what `module:fs` is, but as long as you very sure that structure of both matches then you can use type assertion using `as`.

If you are not sure, then see if you can have something like below:
(Note that this may need some tweaking and i have not tested this)

```js
function isFs(obj: any): pet is module:fs {
  return (obj as module:fs).xxx !== undefined;
}


const getFs = () => {
 const fs = remote.require('fs')
 if(isFs(fs)) return fs
 else throw TypeError(`remote.require('fs') can not be cast to module:fs`)
}

const Fs = getFs()
```